# Cross handler interactions between ScrollView and PanGestureHandler

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-navigation

I have a bottom sheet wrapped in a `PanGestureHandler` from `react-native-gesture-handler`. Inside, there is a header and a ScrollView, imported from the same library mentioned above. I want the PanGestureHandler to take over any time the content offset in the Scrollview is less than or equal to 0 (i.e. at the top). I tried using `simulatenousHandlers` property but it doesn't seem to be working on iOS.

My code for reference:

```
<PanGestureHandler
        ref={panRef}
        onGestureEvent={onGestureEvent}
        onHandlerStateChange={onHandlerStateChange}
        simultaneousHandlers={scrollRef}
      >
        <Animated.View
          style={{
            position: "absolute",
            bottom: 0,
            width: "100%",
            height: height * 0.7,
            transform: [
              {
                translateY: bottomSheetY.interpolate({
                  inputRange: [0, height],
                  outputRange: [0, height],
                  extrapolate: "clamp",
                }),
              },
            ],
          }}
        >
          <HandleHeader imageSource={"https://picsum.photos/300"} />
          <ScrollView
            bounces={false}
            ref={scrollRef}
            scrollEventThrottle={16}
            simultaneousHandlers={panRef}
          >
            <MoreInfo />
          </ScrollView>
        </Animated.View>
      </PanGestureHandler>
```

What can I do in order to achieve my goal?

Comment: What do you want to do when the offset is equal to 0?

Comment: When offset is <=0, I want PanGestureHandler to take over so that the container view starts dragging down.

Comment: Why are not you using `scrollEvent`?

Comment: How would that be helpful in my case?